# How to run a git command in python?

Tags: python, git

The official manual in python 3.6 suggestes using subprocess instead of os.system,

but I find sometime the subprocess do not work,

like if I want to run a git command.

```
os.system("git add .") # This works
gadd = subprocess.run(["git add ."]) # this shows a FileNotFoundError
gadd = subprocess.run(["git", "add ."]) # this shows [git: 'add .' is not a git command.]
```

Well, how can I run this git command correctly in subprocess? I tried call(), it is just the same as run().

I searched in google and stackoverflow, but almost all posts just say how to run 'ls -l'. Well ,that is easy, but this seems not.

Comment: short answer `["git" ,"add" ,"."]`

Comment: "how to run git command in python" on Google gave me enough results. Plus if `ls -l` worked for you then the above should as well.

Comment: Thank you every one...It is awkward... It seems that I should have done more search and more on learning English...